# Automatically adding / modifying usings

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, plugins, namespaces

1. Is there a way to automatically set the namespaces for classes according to a new folder structure, project-wide, so that refactored folders and files align with the default convention of

> namespace project.folder.subfolder

within Visual Studio 2010?

1. After restructuring a project, and changing the namespaces, is there a facility to adjust the using code lines automatically, project-wide with the new namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) handles this nicely with the [Adjust Namespaces](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Refactorings__Adjust_Namespaces.html) functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Within Visual Studio itself, not that I am aware.

The Resharper add-in has an "Adjust Namespaces" feature which will go through a solution and match up namespaces with folder structure. This will also resolve reference re-mapping as well.